# How to use list<T*> as method's parameter?

Tags: c++

How to use generics types as params?
I have two lists

```
list<XmlElement*>* childrens;
list<XmlAttribute*>* attributes;
```

I want transfer this variables as params to method, like this, but it isn't work

```
void method(list<void*>* l);
```

P.S. this code should use the minimum possible amount of memory, because microcontrollers has so little RAM.

Comment: Nope. You can't implicitly convert a `list<XmlElement*>*` to `list<void*>*`.

Comment: For the record, `std::list` is not a good way to use the minimum possible amount of memory (overhead of two `uintptr_t` _per element_, whereas `std::vector` tends to have only three `uintptr_t` in total, beating `std::list` when you have any more than a single element).

Comment: Aside `list<XmlElement*>*` is a gratuitous use of pointers. You probably want `std::vector<XmlElement>`, (or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<XmlElement>>` if `XmlElement` is polymorphic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be template would do the trick ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <class T>
void foo (const std::list<T*>& v)
{
       std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
   std::list<int*> v { nullptr, nullptr };

    foo(v);
}
```